# How to activate free trial for more than one product in Google Inapp Subscription Service?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have defined 5 different products from developer console each having 7-day free trial. Within first days, users were able to get free trial for each of them seperately. I also tried and tested. I were able to start free trial for 2 different products.

However, now when you start one free trial, you are not able to start others. Google prompts you to pay and buy also informs you that you already got a free trial and can't get anymore.

I have noticed in https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#trials that

> You can provide each user with only one free trial, regardless of the number of subscription products that your app offers

Is that new?

Comment: Google made quick changes in the issue. Now it is written as "You can create one free trial period per subscription product.". They reverted the system back.